# Zk: Error writing 'constraint'?

Tags: java, constraints, zk, zul

My zul here:

```
 <intbox id="displayOrder"
    value="@bind(vm.folderProcessRecord.displayOrder)"
    maxlength="6"
    constraint=" @load(vm.getText('FolderProcess:MESSAGE_NO_NEGATIVE'))" 
    tooltiptext="@load(vm.getText('FolderProcess:FIELD_DISPLAY_ORDER'))" />
```

properties file of english and french.

```
    MESSAGE_NO_NEGATIVE=no negative: Value cannot be negative.
```

or

```
   MESSAGE_NO_NEGATIVE=pas négatif: valeur ne peut pas être négatif.
```

my issue is that constraint  work only when select english language .but when i select french language its not read constraint give error .

Error:

```
Error writing 'constraint' on type com.Abcdsystems.Abcd.comp.AbcdIntbox at [file:/C:/Abcd_N_WORKSPACE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/module-web/core/folder_process_edit.zul, line:416]
```

Anyone give me any idea how can resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the : is the actual constraint, after is the "error message".
In the french your setting of the constraint still stays english.
it should be :

```
MESSAGE_NO_NEGATIVE=no negative: valeur ne peut pas être négatif.
```

Greetz chill.